# How many instances of a class have been created

Tags: php, class, oop

I want to know how many instances of a particular class are present in memory.

```
class Test
{
   public function testFunction() { return 'Test'; }
}
```

I create some objects:

```
$test1 = new Test();
$test2 = new Test();
$test3 = new Test();
```

How can I count the number of `Test` objects?

Comment: I doubt such functionality exists.  Though you could easily track it by creating a static value and incrementing/decrementing it in a constructor/destructor.

Comment: [Demo of @David's suggestion](https://3v4l.org/Pasfa)

Comment: Hackish way: `var_dump(new Test());` Will show #4, so ignoring the test one there are 3.

Comment: Could also create an array of objects `$test[] = new Test();` and `echo count($test);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this using a static variable in your class, which you keep updated via it's constructor and destructor. Here is how:

```
class MyClass {
    public static $instanceCount = 0;

    function __construct() {
        self::$instanceCount++;
    }

    function __destruct() {
        self::$instanceCount--;
    }
}

// create 3 instances
$a = new MyClass();
$b = new MyClass();
$c = new MyClass();
echo MyClass::$instanceCount; // outputs: 3

// implicitly lose one instance (destructor is called)
$a = "test";

echo MyClass::$instanceCount; // outputs: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-defined-vars.php) function

It returns an array with defined vars, then you'll need to loop through the array an count by class. To get the class of a given variable you can use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-class.php) function.

Maybe something like this:

```
function countVars() {
   $varsDefined = [];

   foreach(get_defined_vars() as $v) {
      $varClass = get_class($v);

      if (!isset($varsDefined[$varClass])) $varsDefined[$varClass] = 0;

      $varsDefined[$varClass]++;
   }

   return $varsDefined;
}
```

I could´t test the code so it could have some mistakes, but I think the idea is there :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: note that `get_defined_vars `will return all the defined variables within the scope that the function is called. so, at best you can loop all the variabile in global scope (`$_GLOBALS`) and check if it's an instance of `Test`, but that's will work only for global variables.

Comment: @Federico you are right! My answer only works for a particular scope, not for the whole application. The advantage is that you don´t need to touch any class definition to get counting.